# cs50 pset3 - Sorting

Tags: c, cs50

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    int swap, i;
    do{
    swap = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(values[i]>values[i+1]){
            int temp = values[i+1];
            values[i+1] = values[i];
            values[i+1]=temp;
            swap = 1;
            }printf("%d\n", values[i]);
        }
    }while(swap == 1);
}
```

it doesn't seem to be working. what could be wrong?

values: 59797 10425 37569 52527 36285

as sorted: 10425 37569 52527 36285 59797

CHANGED IT

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    int swap, i, temp;
    // TODO: implement an O(n^2) sorting algorithm
    do{
    swap = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(values[i]>values[i+1]){
            temp = values[i+1];
            values[i+1] = values[i];
            values[i]=temp;
            swap = 1;
            }
            printf("%d\n", values[i]);
        }
    }while(swap == 1);
}
```

values: 59797 10425 37569 52527 36285

as sorted: 0
10425
36285
37569
52527

Comment: `values[i+1]=temp;` --> `values[i]=temp;`, `i<n;` --> `i<n-1;`

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger and stepped through it line-by-line *(no, you have not; because if you had, you would know the answer)*

Comment: fixed [DEMO](http://ideone.com/nX2JBX)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY read your program line by line, I got it now. thanks. cs50 ide still doesn't show the 59797 tho but find.c confirms that it is in the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at these two lines.

```
 values[i+1] = values[i];
 values[i+1]=temp;
```

Does it not look like you're setting the same element twice, to two different values, for no effect?

What purpose does the first statement serve? There is your answer.

---

When `i` is its last value (`n-1`), then you will compare `values[n-1]` with `values[n]`.
One of those elements is ***not in your array***.  
You just did an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: just changed it as values[i] = temp and now the sorted value is : 0
10425
36285
37569
52527. "59797" just disappeared

Comment: @trqw2: if `i=n-1` -- your end criterium -- then `values[i+1]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider using built in function. qsort may simplify things.